# Vue.js Two-way Data Binding not working on Select Element

Tags: javascript, data-binding, vue.js

I'm trying to set a value of my select element depending on some condition but the problem is that my model is updating but the DOM isn't.

here's the very basic example of what im trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/chrislandeza/4Ly1xmrx/

Basically just saying that if the value of my select element is 1 then set it to 2

here's the code from fiddle above:

```
    <div id='app'>
        <select v-model="test">
            <option></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
               test: ''
            },
            watch: {
               'test': function (newVal, oldVal) {
                   // some condition
                   if (newVal == 1) {
                        // manually set the value
                        this.test = '2';
                   }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I tried using **method** and put it on the **change event** instead of **watching** the model but it's not working either.

Any thoughts? Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
My temporary solution is to add v-el='test' directive on my select element

```
<select v-model='test' v-el='test'>
```

and manually set the value of the element using **this.$$.test.value = 2** after setting the value of the model.

```
if (newVal == 1) {
     // manually set the value
     this.test = '2';
     this.$$.test.value = 2
}
```

Note: I'm doing a much more complex/realistic thing than this example and 
I'm fine with this solution for now. I'm still looking for a better solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Yea its working correctly if you check the value is changing i dont see the problem.It's the value changing not what is rendered to the page

Comment: That's what I said, the value of my model is correct but my DOM or the selected value of my element is not.

Comment: @ChrisLandeza   change to  **<option value="1">{{test}}</option> **  you will see it change